# Why kendo numericTexBox saved old value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

friends! Please help me fix one problem.
I'm using MVC for nopCommerce project.

I'm  having:

1. Model

```c#
public class DomainSetting:IDomain
{
...
bool UseSlice {get;set;}
int Slices {get;set;}
...
}
```

2. Two methods in the HomeController:

```c#
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
 var model = _settingRepository.getSettings();
 return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SettingModel model)
{
 var domainSetting = _settingRepository.GetSetting(model.settingId);
 domainSetting.ImagesId = model.ImagesId;
 ...
 if(model.UseSlice)
 {
  domainSetting.Slices  = model.Slices;
 }
 ...
 return Edit();
}
```

3. And view "Edit"

```c#
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseSlice)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Slices)
...
```

4. Razor transformed this code in *kendoNumericTextBox* (its correct)

My actions

1. When I checked "UseSlice", changed value of "Slices" and saved form, all working correct.

   - Begin action: in repository - *UseSlice = true,Slice = 3*, model in controller - *UseSlice = true, Slice = 8*.
   - End action: in repository - *UseSlice = true,Slice = 8*, for view - *UseSlice = true,Slice = 8*.
   - Response to browser: *UseSlice = true, Slice = 8*.
2. When I checked "UseSlice", changed value of "Slices", unchecked "UseSlice" and saved form, value of "Slice" didn't change in controller (its correct). Value of "Slice" in Model for view is correct (its old value), but value of "Slice" in response is incorrect -its changed value.

   - Begin action: in repository - *UseSlice = true,Slice = 3*, model in controller - *UseSlice = false, Slice = 8*.
   - End action: in repository - *UseSlice = false,Slice = 3*, for view - *UseSlice = false,Slice = 3*.
   - Response to browser: *UseSlice = false, Slice = 8*.
3. When I added

```
<span>@Model.Slice</span>
```

on the View, its showed Slice correct

My asks:

1. How fix this problem?
2. Where caching old value in *kendoNumericTextBox*?

Thank You.

P.S. Sorry of my bad English

Comment: Not really clear what question is. MVC binds to ModelState values so if your trying to change the value of a property in the POST method then you first need to clear `ModelState` - `ModelState.Clear()` before you update the property and return the view.

Comment: Thank to Stephen Muecke! I added ModelState.Clear()
 in my controller and its working for me